# Cloud Function Cors Policy

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a Cloud Function that has been running for months with no issues, now, all the suddenly, I'm having an error:

> Access to fetch at 'XXXXX' from origin [Site] has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

There was absolutely no updates on the script at all. Has anybody experienced something like this before?

Thanks

Comment: The title says Firebase functions but the tags say Cloud Functions, which are you using?

Comment: Sorry it's Cloud Functions... I was going to write something else and forgot to remove.

Comment: If the script did not change, did the sender (HTTP client) change?

Comment: Hi @iconio, I believe that the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_cors_requests) can give you an idea about how handling CORS works. I believe that the SITE domain is blocking access content and you will need to set the appropriate headers to match the requests that origin SITE wants to accept. Keep me posted!